# Unable to instantiate Go chaincode with Client Identity Chaincode Library on Fabric v1.4

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to instantiate a chaincode where I have implemented the Client Identity Chaincode Library ([docs](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/blob/master/pkg/cid/README.md)). The error I am getting inside the CLI pod is the following

```sh
> peer chaincode instantiate -o ord1.orderers.org1.com:7050 -C mychannel -n mychaincode -v 1.1 -c '{"Args":[]}' --tls --cafile /var/hyperledger/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.orderers.org1.com-cert.pem
2020-11-03 13:52:36.121 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 001 Using default escc
2020-11-03 13:52:36.121 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 002 Using default vscc
Error: could not assemble transaction, err proposal response was not successful, error code 500, msg error starting container: error starting container: Failed to generate platform-specific docker build: Error returned from build: 1 "chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/pkg/attrmgr/attrmgr.go:17:2: cannot find package "github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp" in any of:
        /chaincode/input/src/github.com/chaincode/vendor/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp (vendor tree)
        /opt/go/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp (from $GOROOT)
        /chaincode/input/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp (from $GOPATH)
        /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp
```

My original Go verion was 1.12.x and I found in the fabric-sdk-go docs that it needed version 1.14.x and above so I upgraded to "go version go1.15.2 linux/amd64". The weirdest thing is the directory "/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/msp" exists with all 3 files that is there in the github repo's same path yet it is not able to find it.

I have attached the $GOPATH directory structure[image: gopath directory structure]
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on your peer's go version.

If you use earlier version of go on that case you have to manually place the package into respected directory. So for client Identity Library, you can download the vendor folder.
Tutorial Link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m2ksemtAB10

You can also write a bash file and install dependency into respected folder. Like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Initialize
echo "Initializing ..."
govendor init
govendor add +external


echo "Adding dependencies ... please wait"
#For older setup
# govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim
# govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer
# govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/lib/cid

# For newer setup with Fabric 2.0
govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim
govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/shim/internal
govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/peer
govendor add github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/pkg/cid
```

For newer go version, you can use that too.

```
# before packaging Golang chaincode, vendoring Go dependencies is required like the following commands.
cd /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/chaincode/abstore/go
GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
cd -
```

Link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.0/build_network.html#install-and-define-a-chaincode

I'm giving example for cid, but same goes for attrmgr.